# Maximum volume of the package?

Tags: limits, functions

Here are the restrictions of the package:

-Length+width+height can not be over 90 cm.

-Length can maximum be 60 cm.

-Width=height

What is the maximum voulme of the package? This is what I have done, but unfortunately I'm stuck:

$L+W+H=L+X+X=L+2X=90$

$L=90-2x$

$L\leq60$

$90-2x\leq60$

$x\geq15$

I don't know if I am doing this right or not, and how to find the function of the volume.

Comment: Where is your equation for the volume?

Comment: $L$ is not equal to $90 -2X$.  Instead, $L +2X \leq 90$

Comment: @joe I thought about finding an expression for the length before setting up the function of the volume.

Comment: @Joe Yeah, I see now that I shouldn't used the equal sign.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We want to maximize the volume: $V=xy(90-x-y)$ (because $x+y+z=90$).

Calculating derivatives yields: $\frac{dV}{dx}=y(90-2x-y)$ and $\frac{dV}{dy}=x(90-2y-x)$. Since neither $x$ nor $y$ can be $0$ ($V=0$), hence $90=2x+y=2y+x$.

Final result: max volume (for $x=y=z=30$) $V_{max}=30^3$.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but just wondering about something. Should I not take into account that the length be maximum 60 cm in the calculation?

Comment: And it is. In my opinion the first constraint is sufficient, others are just for distraction.

Comment: Okay, thank you so much be the way! Really appreciate it!

Comment: @Mathomat55, In general, you do have to take that into account in two ways: first you have to check that the points that you find by setting the derivative equal to zero fall within your feasible region (i.e. satisfy constraints). Second, you have to make sure that the local maxima you find (if any) is also the global maximum by checking the boundary.

Comment: @Joe Thanks for the tips!

Comment: You’re welcome!